# Set time_t to unsigned 32-bit int

Tags: c, visual-c++, unsigned, int32, time-t

I'm doing some embedded software and its `time_t` is unsigned 32-bit integer. I have a PC simulator whose `time_t` appears to be signed 32-bit integer. Is there any way to tell Visual C to use `uint32_t`?

Answer (score 0):

The question is unclear. How do "embedded software", "PC simulator" and "Visual C" relate to each other? If the embedded software runs on the PC simulator then **how can their `time_`s have different signnesses**?

Or do you mean the current simulator is built with MSVC and has signed `time_t` so it can't run the embedded software, and you want to rebuild it with MSVC to use unsigned `time_t`? MSVC only supports [32 and 64-bit signed `time_t`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/time-time32-time64?view=vs-2019) so the answer is **No**. If `time_t` is a 32-bit type on your platform (only occurs on very old MSVC versions or newer 32-bit code with `_USE_32BIT_TIME_T`) **and** the software doesn't run beyond [year 2038](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem) then no conversion is necessary. Otherwise you need to rebuild with VS2015+ to use 64-bit `time_t` and write a small wrapper to convert the value when passing to the simulator

```
// Returns true if the time fits in uint32_t
bool simulator_gettime(uint32_t *time)
{
    time_t systemtime;
    time(&systemtime);
    if (difftime(systemtime, (time_t)0xFFFFFFFLL) > 0)
    {
        *time = systemtime;
        return true;
    }
    else // overflow an unsigned 32-bit value
    {
        *time = 0xFFFFFFFFU;
        return false;
    }
}
```